# jQuery ajax dataType script with IE6

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-6

I'm using the following peace of code to do so ajax magic on a page and it works alright for any browser - except, you guessed it, lovely IE6

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type:     "GET",
  url:      jQuery("#filter_form").attr('action'),
  data:     jQuery("#filter_form").serialize(),
  dataType: 'script',
  success:  function(response) { //insert into page }
});
return false;
```

Actually it does render the correct results but is showing an ugly message too - something like "syntax error in line ~2mio"

When I remove the dataType script everything's working but my server responds wrong then the datatype is not set.

Anyone with any idea?

Thanks a lot,
joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the script you're loading: it's there that the IE6-exclusive syntax error will be found ;)